# Prove if $A$ is infinite and $x \notin A$, then $A \cup \left \{ x \right \}$ is infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Prove if $A$ is infinite and $x \notin A$, then $A \cup \left \{ x \right \}$ is infinite

Proof: Let $A$ be infinite. Then $A \approx \mathbb{N}$. Let $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ be a one-to-one correspondence. Then $g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A \cup \left \{ x \right \}$, defined by

$g(t) = \begin{cases}
 x& \text   { if } t= 1\\ 
 f(t-1)& \text{ if } t> 1 
\end{cases}$

is one-to-one and onto $A \cup \left \{x \right\}$. Thus $\mathbb{N} \approx A \cup \left\{x \right\}$, so $A \cup \left\{x \right\}$ is infinite.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: The proof seems to assume A is **countable** and infinite. Is this what you want?

Comment: Infinite does not mean "in bijection with $\mathbb N$".

Comment: If you replace $A$ with a subset $B$ of $A$ with the property that $B\approx \Bbb N$ and then replace '$A$' with '$B$', then it looks fine, but I'd be weary about using things such as $t\color{red}-1$. Has subtraction (in some sense) been defined?

Comment: @Git Gud: I assume from the rest of the post $t$ ranges over the naturals t with $t>1$, so that $t-1$ is defined.

Comment: @user99680 For it to be defined, it has to have been defined, it's not enough that it can be defined and in this context I find it unlikely that it has been so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of "infinite" is "not finite". So the contrapositive is probably easier to prove: "If $x\notin A$ and $A\cup\{x\}$ is finite, then $A$ is finite." is an equivalent statement.

The definition of "finite" is "in bijection with $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ for some nonnegative integer $n$". So by assumption we have a bijection $f$ from $A\cup\{x\}$ to some $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ for some $n$. By composing with the transposition $(n\ f(x))$ if need be, we may assume that $f(x) = n$. Now show that $f$ restricted to $A$ is a bijection bewtween $A$ and $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.